# How to move the background image with keys in pygame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am making a game in pygame. In this game, the background image is large. On the screen, player only sees about 1/20th of the background image. I want, when player presses the left, right, up or down arrow keys, the background image moves respectively, but, it stops moving when player reaches the end of the image. I have no idea how to do this.

My code up to this point :-

```
import pygame

FPS = 60
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
bg = pygame.image.load('map.png')

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()
```

Thanks in Advance :-

Comment: Have you tried drawing part of the background on the screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the sice of the background and the screen by `get_size()`:

```py
screen_size = screen.get_size()
bg_size = bg.get_size()
```

Define the initial start of the background in range [0, `bg_size[0]-screen_size[0]`]. e.g. center of the background:

```py
bg_x = (bg_size[0]-screen_size[0]) // 2
```

Get the list of the key states by `pygame.key.get_pressed()`:

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Change `bg_x` dependent on the state of <kbd>left</kbd> and <kbd>right</kbd>:

```py
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
    bg_x -= 10
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
    bg_x += 10
```

Clamp `bg_x` to the range [0, `bg_size[0]-screen_size[0]`]:

```py
 bg_x = max(0, min(bg_size[0]-screen_size[0], bg_x))
```

`blit` the background at `-bg_x` on the screen:

```py
screen.blit(bg, (-bg_x, 0))
```

See the example:

```py
import pygame

FPS = 60
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000, 1000))
bg = pygame.image.load('map.png')

screen_size = screen.get_size()
bg_size = bg.get_size()
bg_x = (bg_size[0]-screen_size[0]) // 2
bg_y = (bg_size[1]-screen_size[1]) // 2

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True:
    clock.tick(FPS)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            exit()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        bg_x -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        bg_x += 10
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        bg_y -= 10
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        bg_y += 10
    bg_x = max(0, min(bg_size[0]-screen_size[0], bg_x)) 
    bg_y = max(0, min(bg_size[1]-screen_size[1], bg_y))

    screen.blit(bg, (-bg_x, -bg_y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: great, it worked very good. But, for moving up and down. Can we just do the same by making and maintaing a variable called bg_y

Comment: @programmerpro I've extended the example.